# Using array push to concatenate string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, concatenation

In the following section of the tutorial. I see array's push method has been used to concatenate string. 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-selecting-files-input

Example:

```
x = []
x.push('a','b', 'c')
x.join('') //abc
```

I found it interesting. But is it a better practice than the usual string concatenation?

Comment: It's not. They are just different semantically.

Comment: It's actually a pretty bad tutorial in my opinion, why create an array then concatenate the indexes with join.

Comment: Actually that tutorial does make sense, you have no way of knowing if the user has selected 10,000 files.